# My add button in my iOS 10 app is not performing an action

Tags: ios, swift

I started to learn Swift 3 and Xcode a week ago.

At this moment I have an small app with a navigation bar and an add button on the right, I want it to perform something but I can't figure it out...

I have this:

```
func criarPessoa() {
    _ = pessoas.append("Ola OLA")
}

let adicionarButao = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(criarPessoa()(sender:)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let adicionarButao = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(criarPessoa()(sender:)))
```

should be

```
let adicionarButao = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(NameOfTheVCTheFunctionIsIn.criarPessoa()))
```

You also need to add the BarButton like so :

```
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([adicionarButao], animated: false)
```

or:

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([adicionarButao], animated: false)
```